How to install Factory IO in Ubuntu using command terminal
I want to download Factory IO but it is not available in the app center.

Factory IO is a Windows-only application.



Requirement
Details




Operating System
Windows 7 SP1+ or higher


CPU
CPU with SSE2 instruction set support


Graphics API
DX10, DX11, DX12 capable


GPU
NVIDIA since 2006 (GeForce 8), AMD since 2006 (Radeon HD 2000), Intel since 2012 (HD 4000 / IvyBridge)



So you need to run it either inside a VM or using Wine - and by the looks of it you also need to buy a license.
